# How to parse data from component into Guard in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, guard, angular-router-guards, candeactivate

I want to show a prompt on screen to the user if they are trying to navigate away from a page in which they have made changes to a form. I have created a Guard so far, and successfully got it to log something in the console when the user navigates away from this page. But now, I need to show a `Dialog` box warning them, and they should be able to cancel the 'navigation' or confirm that they wish to navigate away.

I have a method in my component containing the form that checks whether or not changes have been made to the form, now I just need to implement the rest described above.

Here is my Guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouterGuardGuard implements CanDeactivate<unknown> {
  canDeactivate(
    component: unknown,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    console.log('TESTING');

    return true;
  }

}
```

I have implemented the guard for my component inside my `app-routing-module.ts` as such:

```
  { path: 'users/edit/:id', canDeactivate: [RouterGuardGuard], component: UserEditorComponent },
```

So, if the user makes changes to the form inside of the `UserEditorComponent` I need to show a dialog box before the navigation occurs, I already have the component for this dialog box, which I use in different parts of my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your `canDeactivate` method to be able to confirm the state of your components form. For that, one way you can do so is to create an interface that when implemented in your component class would return the user's decision to either leave or stay in the component.

In your guard, create an interface like so

```
 export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

In place of type unknown use the interface you have just created:

```
 export class RouterGuardGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate>{...}
```

..and then inside your `canDeactivate` method return:

```
  canDeactivate(
    component: CanComponentDeactivate,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return component.canDeactivate();
  }
```

Now in your component, you need to implement the interface `canComponentDeactivate` that you have created. So inside the `canDeactivate` method that you implement from the interface, access your form and check if it is `touched` or `dirty`. If so prompt the user and return `promise<boolean>` or `boolean`. E.g

```
canDeactivate() {
 if (this.myForm.dirty || this.myForm.touched) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.modalService.create({
          content:
            "Your have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to return?",
          onOk: () => {
            resolve(true);
          },
          onCancel: () => {
            resolve(false);
          },
        });
      });
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks like it makes sense, I am away from my computer at the moment, I will update you once I have implemented it. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Richie nature would you mind elaborating on your last point a bit for me? When you say implement the interface ``canComponentDeactivate``, do you mean inside the component in which my form is? I would assume you mean for example ``export class formComponent implements OnInit, canComponentDeactivate``, but then I am not sure what you mean by "inside the ``CanDeactivate`` method"

Comment: When you indicate in your class that you are implementing the `canComponentDeactivate` interface as you have done in your comment above, you would be required to define the method of that interface which in this case is the `canDeactivate` method. so in your component class:

`canDeactivate() {
  //do your form check as i indicated in my answer
}`
I have made an edit to my answer as well

Comment: thanks a lot, I implemented your solution and it worked as I wanted it to. I Appreciate the help.